# NestJs prisma postgres Error Argument of type

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

**schema.prisma**

```
model User {
  id             Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  user_name      String   @unique
  first_name     String
  last_name      String
  profile_image  String
  password       String
  role           Roles    @default(USER)

  createdAt      DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt      DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt

  @@map("users")
}

enum Roles {
  USER
  ADMIN
}
```

**users.dto.ts**

```
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";

export class CreateUserDto {
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty() user_name: string;

    @IsNotEmpty()
    @ApiProperty() password: string;
}
```

**users.servince.ts**

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { LoginUserDto, CreateUserDto, UpdatePasswordDto } from "./users.dto";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import { PrismaService } from "../prisma/prisma.service";
import { User } from "@prisma/client";

interface FormatLogin extends Partial<User> {
    user_name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

    /* Create User When Register */
    async create (createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
        /* Check if the user exist in the database */
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findFirst({
            where: { user_name: createUserDto.user_name }
        });

        if (user)
            throw new HttpException("user already exists", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
        return await this.prisma.user.create({
            ...(createUserDto),
            role: "USER" as const,
            password: await bcrypt.hash(createUserDto.password, 10)
        });
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> src/users/users.service.ts:26:13 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{
> role: "USER"; password: any; user_name: string; }' is not assignable
> to parameter of type '{ select?: UserSelect; data:
> (Without<UserCreateInput, UserUncheckedCreateInput> &
> UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...> & UserCreateInput); }'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'role' does not
> exist in type '{ select?: UserSelect; data: (Without<UserCreateInput,
> UserUncheckedCreateInput> & UserUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...>
> & UserCreateInput); }'.

**How to resolve this error?**